# Asp.Net - Details Page Multilne

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How do I display details in the details page as multi-line? When I input data to be viewed in the details page it saves side-by-side, whereas I want it to save underneath. I am assuming I will need to change the "col-sm-10" but cannot find the right one to what I want to do. Any help please?

```
<dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Occurance)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Occurance)
        </dd>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code snippet. Inline `style` added for `text-align`

```
            <dt class="col-sm-2">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Occurance)
            </dt>
            <dd class="col-sm-10" style="text-align: initial;">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Occurance)
            </dd>
```

[image: I got the result as in the image.]